# Why is select() not returning back?

Tags: winsock, winsock2

I am trying to understand how to use the `select()` method when dealing with multiple connections in a server program.

```cpp
int Server::handler()
{
    int iResult;
    fd_set activeFdSet;
    fd_set readFdSet;
    FD_ZERO(&activeFdSet);
    FD_SET(soc, &activeFdSet);
    printf("FD_SETSIZE=%d\n", FD_SETSIZE);


    while (1)
    {
        readFdSet = activeFdSet;
        printf("\tCopied activefdset to readfdset\n");
        int res = select(FD_SETSIZE, &readFdSet, NULL,NULL,NULL);
        printf("Return value of select %d\n", res);
    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is one of the functions in the class `Server` that handles connection, `soc` is the `SOCKET` returned by the function `socket()` when creating the server socket.

In this function, it seems that `select()` does not return anything at all since the last `printf()` in the `while` loop does not get printed to the terminal.

This is what my program outputs, and then goes through a loop even when I connect to it.

```
The winsock 2.2 dll was found
Set SO_KEEPALIVE: ON
FD_SETSIZE=64
        Copied activefdset to readfdset
```

Comment: `FD_SETSIZE` is the wrong value to pass in the first parameter of `select()`. On most platforms, it needs to be +1 the highest socket in the `set`. On Windows, the 1st parameter is ignored and should be 0.

Comment: If `soc` is a valid *listening* socket, then `select()` not returning in this code can only mean one thing - that there are no clients connecting to the IP/Port that the server socket is listening on.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select, the `select()` function blocks if the `timeout` argument is NULL. So in the first iteration of the `while` loop, the program will block on the `select()` call until a socket condition is met, therefore not printing the second `printf()` statement.

The conditions which must be met for `select()` to continue execution differ depend on whether you pass `readFdSet` as the 2nd, 3rd or 4th argument (i.e. as `readfds`, `writefds` or `exceptfds`). For `readfds`, `select()` will continue if any of the following conditions apply for the socket in the set:

- If `listen()` has been called on the socket, and a connection is pending, such that the next `accept()` call on it would not block.
- Data is available for reading.
- An accepted connection on the socket has been closed.

After `select()` returns, `readFdSet` will have been modified and contain only those sockets that meet the above conditions. In your case, since `soc` is the only socket in the set, it will contain `soc`.

If you do not want `select()` to block, you can create a `timeval` struct like so:

```
// timeout after 5s
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 5;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
```

Then you can pass it to `select()`:

```
int res = select(FD_SETSIZE, &readFdSet, NULL,NULL, &timeout);
```